# connection time out in firefox browsers

Tags: firefox, time, out

I have for loop which takes about 30 minutes.so when run the browser's time out.I change max execution time in php.INI but give the same error.
I how I can do  to change setting in Firefox?in order my script to run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For altering the connection time out in firefox

1. Open Firefox & type in ‘about:config’ in the address bar & press Enter.
2. Accept 'I'll be careful, I promise' button.
3. Search for network.http.connection-timeout and enter the value(in seconds)